# Каким образом можно выразить абсолютно новое число с обратным порядком цифр введенного числа в C++

Tags: c++

без использования массива, я знаю как вывести это число в обратном порядке но что если новое число мне надо записать в новую переменную

Comment: И что вас смущает? И в чем конкретно вопрос?

Comment: @PeterEliot  Выглядит так, что решение этой задачи тянет на Нобелевскую премию!:) Боюсь, что в природе уже не осталось абсолютно новых чисел!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int a; // Исходное
int b = 0;
while(a)
{
    b = b*10 + a % 10;
    a = a / 10;
}
```

Comment: Может количество ведущих нулей у `b` тоже стоит считать? Впрочем, каков вопрос, таков и ответ.